# Est-ce que « juste mes deux centimes » est une traduction correcte pour « just my two cents »

Tags: traduction

D'après l'[Urban Dictionnary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=my%20two%20cents), « **my two cents** » (parfois $0.02) est

> Une opinion sans conséquente ou un commentaire donné à une autre personne sur un sujet particulier.
>
> (An inconsequential opinion or comment given to another person on a
> particular topic). [...]

Sur [wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/my-two-cents.37694/), on propose des traductions de « my two cents » comme:

> mon grain de sel:
>
> à deux balles

qui semble OK pour moi.

Mais, est-ce que cette traduction: « **juste mes deux centimes** » semble bizzare aux auditeurs francophones ?

Comment: "Inconséquent" does not mean "inconsequential". The translation of "inconsequential" could be "sans importance", "sans conséquences".

Comment: **Juste mes deux centimes** n'est pas une expression idiomatique en France. Peut-être au Québec? Enfin, j'dis ça, j'dis rien...

Comment: Translation doesn't work this way. A good rule of thumb is to ask, "Is everything in my expression literal?" For example, "Am I literally talking about two pennies?" If so, translate word for word. If not — as in this case — ask for similar idioms.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @LukeSawczak, but I have no idea if the word-to-word translation works for the similar idiom because there are some that worked.

Comment: @The-VinhVO It will work sometimes -- when you get lucky. The safer method is to search or ask for equivalents.

Comment: @mouviciel L'idée de mes deux souls ne vaut pas cinq cennes !

Comment: @mouviciel Pas au Québec non plus :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On peut plutôt dire:

> c'est juste mon avis
>
> Je vous donne juste mon avis
>
> je dis ça, je dis rien
>
> à mon humble avis

"Juste mes deux centimes" sera sans doute compris par les gens qui connaissent l'expression anglaise, mais n'est pas courant en français.

*Mettre son grain de sel* a une connotation négative que n'a pas "just my 2 cents": quand on *met son grain de sel*, on s'immisce dans une discussion et on donne son avis sans que personne ne l'ait demandé.

*A deux balles* sera utilisé pour qualifier négativement quelque chose: un *avis à deux balles* par exemple sera un avis jugé de très faible valeur et peu fiable.

Comment: "Je dis ça, je dis rien" s'expose à une réponse du type "bah alors ferme-la", enfin en tout cas de ma part...

Answer (score 3):

C'est pas évident de le traduire en français. Peut-être simplement :

> C'est juste mon avis.

ou

> Voilà ma contribution

Je trouve que l'expression :

> Je dis ça, je dis rien

minimise littéralement les propos tenus ; mais, c'est souvent tout le contraire ! Elle incite sérieusement l'interlocuteur à étudier la contribution.